# Unnest an SQL statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this working SQL statement:

```
select oriseqs.newID from oriseqs WHERE oriseqs.singlets=1 AND 
oriseqs.newID not in (select newID from cleanreport WHERE trash!="")
```

My question is how to avoid doing one select inside another in this particular case. I mean to rewrite the select statement in a way that there is no nested select.

Here is the relevant schema if needed:

```
CREATE TABLE cleanreport(newID TEXT, perc TEXT, inicoord INTEGER, endcoord INTEGER, ilen INTEGER, trash TEXT, comments TEXT);
CREATE TABLE oriseqs(newID TEXT, oldID TEXT, rawseq TEXT, singlets BOOLEAN);
```

Comment: You've left out at least half the schema: what indexes do you have on the two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to approach almost any problem in SQL.  In your particular problem, the first alternative that springs to mind is to use a left outer join and test for null in a joined column on the second table.  However, the query that you have is perfectly reasonable.  I see no reason to change it and doubt - at least upon first inspection - that you'll see better performance from an alternative.

Comment: the good thing about leaving it with a nested query, imho as a QA engineer, is that its easier to reverse engineer the query later on.

Comment: That is another good point.  The purpose of the left outer join solution is not nearly as obvious.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT oriseqs.newID 
FROM oriseqs AS o
LEFT JOIN cleanreport AS cr ON o.newID = cr.newID
WHERE oriseqs.singlets=1 
AND trash != ""
AND cr.newID IS NULL
```

What are the PKs?

Comment: Primary Keys for the two tables. I usually like to check the Primary Key for nullity

Comment: You should move 'AND  trash != ""' to the ON clause. This will change (lessen) which rows are succesfully joined, which will in turn change which are filtered by 'AND cr.newID IS NULL'

Comment: It does not work your query in SQLite :(
Anyway, I will leave it as it (with the nested select), but wanted to try it just for curious.

Answer (score 0):

```
select o.newID 
from            oriseqs     o
left outer join cleanreport c on c.newID = o.newID
WHERE o.singlets=1 
AND c.newID is null;
```